# Array of objects mapping using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm currently working with Vue Js composition API and trying to map project objects into new objects if github_url is not empty.

```
setup(props) {
    type ProjectInterface = {
        id: string;
        name: string;
        client: string;
        description: string;
        website_url: string;
        appstore_url: string;
        playstore_url: string;
        github_url: string;
        youtube_url: string;
        tags: string[];
        images: string[];
    };

    const _props = props;
    let projects = _props.projects_data!;
    projects = projects.map((project: ProjectInterface) => {
        if (project.github_url) {
            return { ...project, test: "hello" };
        }
        return project;
    });
    return { projects };
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend typing `props` in your method declaration and letting the types flow through. For example, the following will work:

```js
type ProjectInterface = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    client: string;
    description: string;
    website_url: string;
    appstore_url: string;
    playstore_url: string;
    github_url: string;
    youtube_url: string;
    tags: string[];
    images: string[];
};

type Props = {
    projects_data?: ProjectInterface[];
}

setup(props: Props) {
    const _props = props;
    let projects = _props.projects_data!;
    projects = projects.map((project) => {
        if (project.github_url) {
            return { ...project, test: "hello" };
        }
        return project;
    });
    return { projects };
}
```

Here's an [associated Typescript playground that works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewFYQMbAJIDtgTgMwENVoBeKAbwCgpaoBLAEwC4oBnYOerAcwG4adLIQC2EVhy68BdKKgA29CDgmdu-QbUYQ2qLmGD0EWVVI2yA7hABGbergD6AVzjzT6mXUJgwHBHAhnV3dpTSgweUIQPwCgt3Y1UNkeewALJ2s4kPM6EAQnYAzAl3jJDzDgQh42bIBtAF1PWnoRKp06xqoAXwEqUEhYRF8ocmpZMEQUdDYHRkJKgH5WeGQ0TBw8IhIGgS6qKnwnLHQjLHYIQrAACgmEX2WhtgBKSjDUYw4oB1vh8h+2JpQeQXcKTNZsEZff4AOluU2AMzmlQAhIC4eDIejptDWtcbmD0C9SAA+V6yWT0fBQfGrdDQlLAdKZEovMbk9kBQpwM4UKDQ-lY4AAGiguA4rAARKkIPJ5AgJVAemFZHt2bROS4zoLAV0noCNdzKKDaQjFbsgA).

That being said, I would consider not using the non-null operator (!). If you *know* that it won't be null or undefined, then remove that option from the type definition. However, if it might be null or undefined, handle that case somehow (e.g., return early or use an empty array).